# How to lock resource when using BeginInvoke for multithreading?

Tags: c#, multithreading, parsing

I have one method which parses some data belonging to a certain user and saves it to the database.

```
delegate void parseUserDataDelegate(string pathToFile);
```

I created a delegate for it and render with BeginInvoke for parallel processing.

```
parseUserDataDelegate deleg = new parseUserData(this.parseUserData);
IAsyncResult result = deleg.BeginInvoke(path, null, null);
deleg.EndInvoke(result);
```

The problem is that there are two tables - one for the data where the foreign key is userid and another table for the user. When there's no corresponding user while parsing the method adds a new entry to the user table and uses its id. There are about 100 entries in data table for one user. The problem is that when all data of the first user is processed, an error is raised because two threads try to create the same entry for the second user. How can I lock access to the user table for different threads?

Comment: If you call BeginInvoke immediately followed by EndInvoke, there's no parallel processing. The thread calling EndInvoke will wait for the operation to complete.

Comment: i would suggest that u check the new users first before doing any transaction. Insert them, then work only on the second table...Unless i missed some of ur logic

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your code. I would suggest the place where method for looking for user and optionally creating new user enclose into lock block.

```
lock(NewUserSync)
{
  FooBar();
}
```

where NewUserSync is plain object shared between these worker threads. If the parsing code is in class, then it's created in ctor (before the method is started on multiple threads). The user IDs can be of course cached in some shared object (thread safety required).